# Volatility of basket with constituents priced in different currencies

Tags: volatility, basket

I'm wondering how the volatility of basket of constituents priced in different currencies can be calculated (without upfront bringing constituent price to basket currency) form volatilities of constituents.

Let's consider linear basket $$B = \Sigma_{i=1}^n\omega_i c_if_i$$ where $\Sigma_{i = 1}^n \omega_i = 1$ and  $\omega_i>0$ for $i = 1\dots n$, $c_i$ is i-constituent price and $f_i$ is fx rate from i-constituent currency to basket currency. Let's assume both $c$ and $f$ are stochastic, log normal and correlated.

For monocurrency basket ($f_i = 1 \ $ ) situation is clear: $ \sigma_B^2 = \Sigma_{i,j}\omega_i \omega_j\sigma_i\sigma_j\rho_{i,j} $, but how to deal with $f_i\ne 1$ setup? Any insights would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any assumptions about the correlation between changes in price c_i and in fx rate f_i?

Comment: @DimitriVulis Thank you for comment. There is no special assumption about correlation between changes in  price c_i and fx_i, except the fact that it is non 0. Also different fx rates can be correlated.